# Selecting file of input type file on load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a file input. When I'm creating the edit form, I get the [Chose file] button and file not chosen, even if I have already have file, and I must re-select it every time I edit something, even if I don't want to change the file. It seem the selected file is not a HTML attribute, because when I chose a file, noting changes there.

**Edit:**

```
<input type="file" id="product_image" name="product[image]" required="required">
```

On default this element look like:
[image]

I want to change it like this:   [image]
on load - change the selected file dynamically/

Comment: add some code, becouse it's a little dificult to understand what behavior do you get and what are you expecting for

Comment: Please share some code, so that we can help you out with your problem.

Comment: edited and added more info

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature of web browsers. They don't allow the developer of the page to programmatically select a file from the user's file system, the user has to do it themselves. When the form is reset (page refresh, rerender and similar events), the user has to select it again.

Many web pages have solved this by uploading the file with AJAX immediately when one is selected and then storing it in the session on the server. Then when the form is reset, the web page can simply show information about this version of the file that resides in the session and possibly offer the ability to remove it and/or select another file.